# Antenna gain, effective aperture and SNR

Tags: rf, antenna, modeling

I'm trying to predict the SNR of different antenna. I have a good propagation model to calculate path loss/received power. My question is in the signal-to-noise ratio equation there are terms, Ae, for effective aperture and Gr for the receive antenna's gain.
$$SNR=\frac{P_{REC}G_RA_E}{kTB}$$
My question is when modeling an antenna from the manufacturer's data sheet does the gain they provide already include the effective aperture or does it need to be included explicitly as in the question?

For example, I am interested in the calculating the SNR for a log periodic antenna which the manufacturer says has a gain of 6dBi over some band.

Do I need to modify this by $$A_e=\lambda^2/4\pi$$ Or is that inherently captured in the 6dBi given by the manufacturer?

Comment: What is meaning of "power received"? the field strength? or the energy exiting the antenna coax-cable?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf received power here is $$P_{REC}=P_{RAD} - Path Loss$$